# Mysql : select a "rollback" query (visualizing the rollback query)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, rollback

The state of these two row are set to 1. I want to set them to 0 and visualizing the result of a `rollback` query  . 
This query does the job :

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE jkm_content SET state=0 WHERE title IN ('001','002');
SELECT * FROM jkm_content WHERE title IN ('001','002');
```

-> The state of the rows outputted are set to 0

However, it's better to close the start transaction with `ROLLBACK` but when my query is...

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE jkm_content SET state=0 WHERE title IN ('258.txt','259.txt');
SELECT * FROM jkm_content WHERE title IN ('258.txt','259.txt');
ROLLBACK;
```

-> ... the state of the rows outputted are set to 1 (the current set not the `start transaction` one! )

What should be my query to output state=0 even if I end my query with `rollback` ?

Comment: You write commit in the first phrase, but later you mention rollback. I think you mix something. Or at least your intention is not clear for me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the question. 
 I used commit because -to me- the rollback query if like a draft before the commit query. Maybe it'snt the way it should be used but I guess it does the job!

Answer (score 0):

Rollback means go back in time to the beginning of the transaction. Everything happened between the start transaction and the rollback will be discarded. I think you need a save checkpoint or similar feature. (I don't know whether it exists under mysql or not.)